# im trying to create something with the time attribute in javascript and it dosn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to do a simple if statment that when the time>7 it will do something and when time<16 it will do something. after I checked in JShint.com for errors and fixed the errors the function still dosn't work, its just it's just display nothing and I dont know what is the problem..

below I wrote the code

thanks in advance for the help!

```
var avucado =  ["eggs ","avucado ","tommato ","mayonnaise ","pickles ","gamba"];
var eggSalad =  ["eggs ","dill ","mayonnaise ","pickles"];
var tuna =   ["tuna ","coriander ","pickles ","mayonnaise ","gamba"];
var cheeze = ["yellow cheeze ","mayonnaise ","tommato ","cucumber"];
var sausage =["sausage ","mustard ","mayonnaise ","tommato ","pickles"];
var choice1 = ("you chose:");
var choice2 = ("the ingredients of your sandwich are:");
var lunch = input.value;
/*jslint evil: true */  
/*jshint multistr: true */

function food (){
  if (time>7){
switch(lunch){
  case 'avucado':
    document.write(choice1 + " " + 'avucado.'+ "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 + 
    " " + avucado + ".");
    break;
  case 'egg salad':
    document.write(choice1 + " " + 'Egg salad.'+ "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 + 
    " " + eggSalad + ".");
    break;
  case 'tuna':
    document.write(choice1 + " " + 'Tuna.'+ "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 + 
    " " + tuna + ".");
    break;
  case 'yellow cheeze':
    document.write(choice1 + " " + 'Yellow cheeze.'+ "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 + 
    " " + cheeze + ".");
    break;
  case 'sausage':
    document.write(choice1 + " " + 'Sausage.'+ "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 + 
    " " + sausage + ".");
    break;
  default:
    document.write("we dont have " + lunch + " yet, but! you can send us \
    mail and we will make that sandwich for you anyway!");
}else{document.write("you'll get you'r order tomorrow by 7AM");
     }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the console for any errors? It's probably letting you know what the problem is. Please be sure to always explain exactly what "does not work" means. Do you see anything on the screen? Is it when you click? Wrong results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
}else(time<24)
```

You want this:

```
}else if(time<24)
```

---

The way you have it now, your `else` clause is not a conditional statement.

---

When I put your code in http://www.jshint.com/, there are other code issues.  You really ought to be checking the error console because it would probably show you script errors.  In any case, here's a fixed up version of your code that passes jsHint's checks for legal javascript:

```
var avucado = ["eggs ", "avucado ", "tommato ", "mayonnaise ", "pickles ", "gamba"];
var eggSalad = ["eggs ", "dill ", "mayonnaise ", "pickles"];
var tuna = ["tuna ", "coriander ", "pickles ", "mayonnaise ", "gamba"];
var cheeze = ["yellow cheeze ", "mayonnaise ", "tommato ", "cucumber"];
var sausage = ["sausage ", "mustard ", "mayonnaise ", "tommato ", "pickles"];
var choice1 = ("you chose:");
var choice2 = ("the ingredients of your sandwich are:");
var food = function () {

    if (time < 7) {
        var lunch = input.value;
        switch (lunch) {
        case 'avucado':
            document.write(choice1 + " " + 'avucado.' + "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 +
                " " + avucado + ".");
            break;
        case 'egg salad':
            document.write(choice1 + " " + 'Egg salad.' + "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 +
                " " + eggSalad + ".");
            break;
        case 'tuna':
            document.write(choice1 + " " + 'Tuna.' + "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 +
                " " + tuna + ".");
            break;
        case 'yellow cheeze':
            document.write(choice1 + " " + 'Yellow cheeze.' + "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 +
                " " + cheeze + ".");
            break;
        case 'sausage':
            document.write(choice1 + " " + 'Sausage.' + "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 +
                " " + sausage + ".");
            break;
        default:
            document.write("we dont have " + lunch +
                " yet, but! you can send us mail and we will make that sandwich for you anyway!");
        }
    } else if (time < 24) {
        document.write("you'll get your order tomorrow by 7AM");
    }
}
```

Comment: @GuySolell - what doesn't work?  Specifically, for which value of `time` does it not do what you want?  Also, did you check the error console to see if any script errors are being reported that are keeping your scripts from executing?

Comment: its just dosent display my the things on the screen, I guess there's something wrong with time becuase when I created this function I started without the time attribute and everything worked fine. and what is console? im new to javascript and im using notepad++.

Comment: @GuySolell - I added more to my answer after jsHint showed a bunch of other issues in your code.  You really should learn to use tools like the debug console (where you see script errors) and tools like jsHint.com that flag wrong or potentially wrong code.  P.S. you might want to look up the spelling of `avucado`.

Comment: thank you ver much! i'll check the jshint im sure it will save me some questions here! and thanks about the avocado ;)